# yii2 - How to translate a word dependent both on plurals and genders

Tags: php, yii2, localization, internationalization

How can i achieve dependent translation both on plural and gender of a single word.

I am aware how can translate the word depending on pluralization:

```
Yii::t('app', '{n,plural,=1{Approved} other{Approved}}', ['n' => 0])
```

and also for gender:

```
Yii::t('app', '{gender,select,feminine{Approved} masculine{Approved} other{Approved}', ['gender' => 'feminine']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii 2 uses ICU, which allows you to nest gender and plural rules. Something like this should work:

```
Yii::t(
    'app',
    '{gender,select,'
    . 'feminine{{n,plural,=1{Approved} other{Approved}}} '
    . 'masculine{{n,plural,=1{Approved} other{Approved}}} '
    . 'other{{n,plural,=1{Approved} other{Approved}}}'
    . '}',
    [
        'gender' => 'feminine',
        'n' => 0,
    ]
);
```

See also example in ICU documentation: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages

Comment: i was wondering is nesting possible, i tried your suggestion but i get "n,plural,=1{Approved} other{Approved}"

Comment: @tsanchev I fixed my example, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how to do this directly. You can make a workaround by making a helper method that would join the two params together.

```
class TranslationHelper
{
    protected static function countToString($count)
    {
        if ($count === 1) {
          return 'sin';
        }
        retrun 'plu';
    }

    public static function joinGenderAndCount($gender, $count)
    {
        return $gender . '-' . static::countToString($count);
    }
}
```

Then you would use it in transaltion with select like this

```
Yii::t(
    'app',
    '{genderPl,select,feminine-plu{Approved} feminine-sin{Approved} masculine-plu{Approved} masculine-sin{Approved} other{Approved}',
    [
        'genderPl' => TranslationHelper::joinGenderAndCount('feminine', 1)
    ]
);
```

If you need more complex plural rules you can use `Yii::t` inside of the `countToString` method to get correct plural rules applied.

```
protected static function countToString($count)
{
    return Yii::t(
        'other-category',
        '{n,plural,=1{sin} one{sin} few{few} many{plu} other{plu}'
        ['n' => $count]
    );  
}
```

I would suggest keeping this type of 'internal' translation in different category to prevent conflicts with standard translations.